# show that $X \setminus A \subset B \iff A \cup B =X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

assuming $A \subset X$ and $B \subset X$

show that $X \setminus A \subset B \iff A \cup B =X$

---

2 parts

i) $X \setminus A \subset B \Rightarrow  A \cup B =X$

ii) $X \setminus A \subset B \Leftarrow  A \cup B =X$

---

**part i)**

Assuming that $X \setminus A \subset B$
$$\begin{aligned}
A \cup B \supset A \cup (X \cap A^c)= (A \cup A^c) \cap (A \cup X)
   = U \cap (A \cup X)=A \cup X
\end{aligned} $$
since $A \subset X$ , $A \cup X =X$ thus $A \cup B \supset X$. And $A \cup B \subset X$ is clear.*[ $\therefore$  if   $X \setminus A \subset B$ then $A \cup B =X$]*

*part ii) I did not prove it like part a had to use element argument to reach a contradiction.* **Is there a way to prove part ii like part i? without using element argument ??**

**anyways,** 
$A \cup B =X \Rightarrow x \setminus A \subset B$

so

$$A \cup B  =X \equiv x\in A \wedge x\in B \iff x\in X $$

consider $$x\in X \cap A^c \equiv x\in X \wedge  x \not \in A$$

ussing part of the assumption that $$x\in X \Rightarrow x\in A \wedge x\in B$$

so $x\in X \wedge x \not\in A \Rightarrow (x\in A \vee x\in B )\wedge x \not \in A $
using disjoint syllogims $x\in B $

***or more elegant way to do part ii??***

Comment: You want to use $\subseteq$, not $\subset$.

Comment: @ElliotG $\subsetneq$ and $\subseteq$ are non-interchangeable, but $\subset$ could be either. In fact, I've seen it mean $\subseteq$ more often.

Comment: ii) $X \setminus A = (A \cup B) \setminus A \subset B$

Comment: that works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1**: $X\setminus A\subseteq B\implies X=A\cup B$.

Suppose $x\in X$. Then, if $x\in A$, $x\in A\cup B$. If $x\notin A$, then $x\in X\setminus A\subseteq B$. Thus $X\subseteq A\cup B$.

Suppose $y\in A\cup B$. By assumption, $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X$, so $y\in X$. Thus $A\cup B\subseteq X$.

**Claim 2**: $X=A\cup B\implies X\setminus A\subseteq B$.

Let $x\in X\setminus A$. Then $x\in X$ and $x\notin A$. Since $X=A\cup B$, this means that $x\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

i) $X \setminus A= X\cap A^c\subseteq A^c$ and $X \setminus A \subseteq B \subseteq X$. Hence we can conclude:
$$X\setminus A\subseteq B\cap A^c =B\setminus A \subseteq X\setminus A  $$
So we have $X\setminus A= B\setminus A.$ From here we get $X=A\cup B,$ because suppose $X$ is "bigger" than that, then $X=A\cup B\cup C$ for some $C\neq \emptyset$ and not subset of $A$ or $B$.  And we will easily get contradiction that $C$ has to be empty set.

ii) If $X=A\cup B$, then $X\setminus A = B\setminus A\subseteq B.$